# Clojure multiply first n elements in sequence by 'x' non recursive

Tags: loops, clojure, non-recursive

I am a newbie in clojure and came across a problem which says, multiply first n elements in a sequence by some number 'x' (non recursively). So for example

```
 (multiply-n-by-x [1 2 3 4 5] 2 10) => [10 20 30 4 5]
```

So here i understood that i need to loop over the sequence n times and then stop, but i am unable to do that. If someone could guide me on how to do about it, it would be great.

Comment: Take a look at `take` and `take-last`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as Shawn's answer but with destructuring and `split-at` (a bit less redundant):

```
(defn multiply-n-by-x [s n x]
  (let [[s1 s2] (split-at (inc n) s)]
    (concat (map #(* x %) s1) s2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way is :

```
(defn multiply-n-by-x [seq n m]
    (concat (map #(* m %) (take (inc n) seq)) (drop (inc n) seq) )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
(defn multiply-n-by-x [sq n x]
  (for [i (range (count sq)) ;for i in range 0 to number of elements in sq
        :let [element (nth sq i)]] ;bind element to the nth item in sq
    (if (<= i n) ;if index below n, return the multiplied element, otherwise return the element as is
      (* x element)
      element)))
```

whatever you return inside the for macro gets put into a sequence so the end result is collection.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy sequences capture delayed recursion. `take`, `drop`, `split` and `for` are lazy constructions. We can avoid them by computing the altered head of the sequence eagerly, as follows:

```
(defn multiply-n-by-x [coll n x]
  (loop [head [], coll coll, n n]
    (if (and (seq coll) (>= n 0))
      (recur (conj head (* (first coll) x)) (rest coll) (dec n))
      (concat head coll))))
```

For example,

```
(multiply-n-by-x [1 2 3 4 5] 2 10)
;(10 20 30 4 5)
```

---

By the way, the convention in Clojure is to give the count of a slice, not the index of the final element, which is one less.

```
(range 3)
;(0 1 2)
```

Comment: wouldnt loop/recur count as recursion, since internally the compiler converts it to recursion?

Comment: @HarshShah I think it's the other way round:`recur` is a recursive *construct* that the compiler translates into a loop. [The official docs](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(recur%20exprs*)) describe its action as a *jump*.